# Why are the categories being pulled from the default posts post type and not my custom post type open-positions?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to pull a list of the categories in my custom post type. My taxonomy of the custom post type  is set to categories, my post type is Open Positions (open-positions).

The shortcode displays the categories from the default post type "posts" instead of the categories from my custom post type.

I used ACF to add the custom post type (FYI).

I have 4 categories (3 with published posts and 1 with a drafted post).

When I execute this code and use the shortcode to display on a page, I am getting the single "uncategorized" category from normal posts NOT my CPT. I expected to see 3 categories that are under my custom post type.

Code being used:

```
function display_custom_post_type_categories() {
    // Change 'your_custom_post_type' to the name of your custom post type
    $post_type = 'open-positions';

    // Get the categories associated with the custom post type
    $categories = get_categories(array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'category', // Change to the taxonomy you are using
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => 1, // Set to 0 if you want to display empty categories
        'post_type'  => $post_type,
    ));

    // Display the categories in a list
    if ($categories) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo 'No categories found.';
    }
}

// Create a shortcode to use in your pages or posts
function custom_post_type_categories_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    display_custom_post_type_categories();
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode('display_custom_post_type_categories', 'custom_post_type_categories_shortcode');
```